# Best tools to develop using the AMD pattern and build a minified file without it

Tags: javascript, package-manager

In a my custom library I'm successfully using **require.js** for developing and the tool [AMDClean](https://github.com/gfranko/amdclean) with **grunt** to build the release version.

Now I'm becoming really frustrated trying to use this in a web application that uses a lot of external libraries downloaded using **bower**.

For example:

- A library declares to support AMD, but its language file doesn't!
- AMDClean has [problems](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1797) with some libraries.
- I tried also **almond.js** and I found problems too (a library uses the function `require.specified` that isn't defined inside almond.js).

I specify that I know how configure require.js; this problems are related to bad written libraries that unfortunately I need to use.

A guy suggested me to use JSPM and Webpack instead of bower.

What do you use in similar situations?